Big O notation exercise
I'm trying to proof that $(n+2)3^n = O(4^n/n)$. I can't use limits. I try in this way but i don't if it is correct.
$\left(n+2\right)3^{n\:}<2n3^n $
$2n3^n\:\le \frac{4^n}{n} $
$2n^2\:\le \frac{4^n}{3^n}$
$2n^2\:\le \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^n$
$n\:\ge\:\log_{\frac{4}{3}}\left(2n^2\right)\:\:\:$
$n\:\ge\:2\log_{\frac{4}{3}}\left(2n\right)\:\:\:\:$
$n\ge2\left(\log_{\frac{4}{3}}\left(2\right)+\:\log_{\frac{4}{3}}\left(n\right)\right)$
so I can use $c = 4$.

You need to put dollarsigns around your LaTeX text, or it won't be processed as LaTeX.

The step $\log (2 n^2)\longrightarrow 2\log (2n)$ is a calculation error. Also can you explain the conclusion: what is $c$ and why can you use $c=4$ ?

How did $\leq$ turn into $\geq?$

@Gribouillis right. I need to find a constant c so that $(n+2)3^n <= c4^n/n.$ Looking at the final inequality I thought that c = 4 might be right, but I don't know and that's why I posted the procedure I did to see if it was correct

Also, $\log(2n^2)\neq 2\log(2n).$ The right side is larger.

We want to find a constant $ c$ such that
\begin{equation}n \left(n+2\right) {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{n}  \leqslant  c\end{equation}
For $ x  >  0$, let
\begin{equation}f \left(x\right) = \log  \left(x \left(x+2\right) {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{x}\right) = \ln  x+\ln  \left(x+2\right)+x \ln  \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\end{equation}
We have
\begin{equation}{f'} \left(x\right) = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+2}+\ln  \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\end{equation}
We see that $ {f'} \left(x\right)$ decreases and also
that $ {f'} \left(6\right)  >  0  >  {f'} \left(7\right)$. Hence
$ f \left(x\right)$ reaches a unique maximum in the
interval $ \left]6 , 7\right[$. It follows that for $n\in  {\mathbb N}$,
\begin{equation}n \left(n+2\right) {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{n}  \leqslant  \max  \left({e}^{f \left(6\right)} , {e}^{f \left(7\right)}\right) = \max  \left(48 {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{6} , 63 {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{7}\right)=48 {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{6}\end{equation}

The fundamental way to prove this sort of bound is to use $e^x>x^m/m!$ for any natural $m$ and $x\geq 0.$
Then $$\left(\frac43\right)^n=e^{n\ln(4/3)}>n^3\frac{\ln^3(4/3)}{3!}$$
Rearranging, we get: $$n^23^n<\frac{3!}{\ln^3(4/3)}\frac{4^n}{n}.$$
You can probably get it from here.
